# How are DateTime values rounded in EF

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2005

When I use a `DateTime` property in EF, this gets mapped to an sql `DateTime` field. The precission provided with that is sufficient for me, but since it is part of a key, I need a way to check if a value is already in the database. How are `DateTime` .NET datatypes rounded to `DateTime` SQL datatypes by the EF?

Comment: to check the key you don't need to know about a "rounding". If you use `context.DbSet<T>().Any(x => x.DateField == SomeDateValue)` you will now if the key exists or not.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I'm answering my own question below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entity framework sends the data to the database as

```
thedatetime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Sql server rounds this as follows:

```
0.899 <= x < 0.992 -> 0.900
0.992 <= x < 0.995 -> 0.903
0.995 <= x < 0.999 -> 0.907
```